# how to set the format of the ticks of the colorbar when plotting the heatmap in Julia?

Tags: julia, heatmap, colorbar, formatter

I'm new to Julia and have trouble plotting using Julia.

[image]

On the right side of the above plots,

The ticks of the colorbar in Hx_trs, and Hz_trs are not readable.

I want to print it in scientific notation, like 2e-6.

But I don't know how to do it...

the part of my code is written below:

```
trsfields = cat(real(Ex_trs), real(Hx_trs), real(Ey_trs), real(Hy_trs), real(Ez_trs), real(Hz_trs), dims=3)
ps = []
for (i, slice) in enumerate(eachslice(trsfields, dims=3))
    name = title[i]*"_trs"
    p = heatmap(slice, title=name, c=:coolwarm)
    push!(ps, p)
end
l = @layout([a d; b e; c f;])
plot(ps..., layout=l, plot_title="trs", size=(1200, 1000))
savefig("trs.png")
```

Here, `trsfields` is rank 3 tensor with size of (100, 150, 6).
Each plot is a slice of the `trsfields` along the 3rd axis.

What keyword argument should I use when using the heatmap function?

I have searched for it in StackOverflow, Google, Official docs, and ChatGPT but couldn't find how.

Comment: Search Julia Discourse as well. This recent one might be relevant: https://discourse.julialang.org/t/colarbar-equal-sized-color-rectangles/99932

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```
using Plots
pyplot()
heatmap(rand(10,10);colorbar_ticks=(0.1:0.1:0.9, Printf.format.(Ref(Printf.format"%.3E"), 0.1:0.1:0.9)))
```

[image]